# transfer the value from def() to another def()

Tags: python, function, telebot

How can I transfer the value of the mes variable from one function to another?

```
def forwardmes2withdelay(message):
    print(message.text)
    if message.text == 'Главное меню':
        button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        contacts = types.KeyboardButton('Контакты')
        post = types.KeyboardButton('Разместить пост')
        button.add(contacts, post)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Главное меню', parse_mode='')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите действие', reply_markup=button)
    else:
        try:
            mes = message.id
            return mes
        finally:
            mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Укажите желаемое вами время формата <i>ЧЧ:СС</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, forwardmestime)



def forwardmestime(message):
    print(mes)
    timeobj = datetime.strptime(message.text, '%H:%M').time()
    if f'{currentdatetime.hour}:{currentdatetime.minute}' == f'{timeobj.hour}:{timeobj.minute}':
        bot.copy_message(chat2, message.chat.id, mes)
    else:
        def tusk():
            bot.copy_message(chat2, message.chat.id, mes)
            return schedule.CancelJob
        schedule.every().day.at(f'{timeobj}').do(tusk)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I want the mes value from the first function to go to another

Comment: What you call a `def()` is called a "function". I suggest you read more about how functions work in python. In particular, pay attention to how you can call a function to make it do some work, pass values to the function as parameters, and return a result back. These are all fundamental concepts that are covered in any good python tutorial online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to have your def functions inside the class.

Second. you need to have your variables declared inside that class.

This way you can change that variable in one function and then use it in another function. Just like the example below.

To access it you need to use "self."

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None

    def changeNameToJames(self):
        self._name = "James"

    def nameIs(self):
        print(self._name)
```

Comment: Everything written here is correct, but OP should also learn how to pass and return values. Usually that is better than mutating a value in one function and reading it in another.